# Linq Expression - Set nested property values

Tags: c#, linq

I have been using the following method to set certain properties to `null`, which works great:

```
    public static void Detach<TObject>(TObject parentObj, params Expression<Func<TObject, object>>[] detachEntities)
    {
        foreach (var detachEntity in detachEntities)
        {
            var prop = (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)detachEntity.Body).Member;
            prop.SetValue(parentObj, null);
        }
    }
```

To call the method, I use: `Detach(personObj, x => x.Car)` - pretty simple

But I'm trying to do the following:

```
Detach(personObj, x => x.Car.Make);
```

-or-

```
Detach(personObj, x => x.Dogs.Select(s => s.Breed), x => x.Car.Make);
```

Thus I'm trying to get each property in the expression and set it's value to `null`.

Any assistance would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this might not be perfect, but it's working - I'm open to any improvements:

```
public static void Detach<TObject>(TObject parentObj, params Expression<Func<TObject, object>>[] detachEntities)
        {
            foreach (var detachEntity in detachEntities)
            {
                var methodCallExpression = detachEntity.Body as MethodCallExpression;
                var member = methodCallExpression?.Arguments[0] as MemberExpression;
                PropertyInfo prop;
                if (member != null)
                {
                    prop = (PropertyInfo)member.Member;
                    prop.SetValue(parentObj, null);
                }

                var memberExpression = detachEntity.Body as MemberExpression;
                var expression = memberExpression?.Expression as MemberExpression;                

                switch (memberExpression?.Expression.NodeType)
                {
                    case ExpressionType.Parameter:
                        prop = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;
                        prop.SetValue(parentObj, null);
                        break;
                    case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                        if (expression != null)
                        {
                            prop = (PropertyInfo)expression.Member;
                            prop.SetValue(parentObj, null);
                        }
                        break;
                }               
            }
        }
```